How to make an irregular smooth border with CSS
Due to an error I created this irregular border for an image that I have to be honest I really like.
Look at the code in the snippet.
How beautiful it's the results!


.smoothed {
      height: 140px !important;
        /* background: red; */
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding: 10px 3px 38px 1px;
}
html, body { background-color: black; color: white; font-family: sans-serif; }
<p>GOOD RESULT</p>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/53/f7/45/53f745aad228c9eddb1adc8bd212cca1.jpg" class="smoothed">

<p>BAD RESULT</p>
<img src="https://as2.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/00/53/72/03/1000_F_53720345_h0zZ8cKmJZyPoKTnn2bsjArj00zn49hc.jpg" class="smoothed">



But the problem is that it works correctly only for square images.
Also I have difficulty putting it in a p paragraph or in another tag like for example <h1> with the same size as the text (talking about the height).
Can someone help me standardize the result so that it works for all images with any size and that it can be put in a tag like <h1> so that the part of the image displayed is roughly a circle? (Can you also use others tags in which to wrap img before putting it in h1 the important thing is that it works.

What do you mean: "it works only for square images" ? you apply a border-radius to not square images, it won't be a circle.

Hi @ Vincent Decaux "that it works only for square images" means that "You apply a border-radius to not square images, it won't be a circle". YEAHHHHH! It's this the problem!   Must become something like a circle from each size image.

try to resize your image to be a square anytime (or any other ratio), then use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit && https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position  to clip parts of image

@CssHTMLearnerMaOKiaOKaO how do you want to create a circle from a rectangle.. ? Don't think about CSS or coding, think about logic.

@ G-Cyrillus you hit the nail on the head. It should be wrapped in something like a div to make it a square (like in the mozilla links you posted about object-fit) without deforming it and then made wavy like you saw in the snippet above.

@ Vincent Decaux "how do you want to create a circle from a rectangle.. ? Don't think about CSS or coding, think about logic."--> look at @G-Cyrillus comment. 'By


aspect-ratio :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio
object-fit
:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit
object-position
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position

might help
Possible fix :


.smoothed {
      height: 140px !important;
      aspect-ratio:1;
        /* background: red; */
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding: 10px 3px 38px 1px;
      object-fit:cover;
      object-position: top center;
}
html, body { background-color: black; color: white; font-family: sans-serif; }
<p>GOOD RESULT</p>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/53/f7/45/53f745aad228c9eddb1adc8bd212cca1.jpg" class="smoothed">

<p><del>BAD</del> RESULT</p>
<img src="https://as2.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/00/53/72/03/1000_F_53720345_h0zZ8cKmJZyPoKTnn2bsjArj00zn49hc.jpg" class="smoothed">



If it does not render circles, it is because of the padding and border-box defaut value

@ G-Cyrillus WOOWOWOW. You put it directly object-fit:cover; object-position: top center;in the img tag keeping the aspect-ratio. I didn't think it was possible. I thought it was reserved for div. Top answer. Green tick. World Champion №1 Nice that you removed the "BAD" with <del>. You're funny. Bye
